# Laravel 5 How to change a model database connection within controller

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

My app should connect to an internal and two external commercial SQL databases.

So, I have several models with a connection to an external an MS-SQL database.

The model looks something like that:

```
class version_Jato extends Model
{
    //
    protected $connection = 'sqlJato';
    protected $table = 'version';
....
}
```

Until now, everything OK, app works with two databases.

I want to change $connection variable within the controller to let's say

```
version_Jato-> $connection = 'sqlJato2'.
```

Is this possible?

Because I have two SQL databases identical as structure only the data is different between them and I don't want to double all the models and the code in the controllers.

Thank you very much for your attention!

Comment: If something is `protected`, what does that mean for external entities? (tip: encapsulation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch the connection using the `on()` static method:

```php
YourModel::on('connection_name')->get();
```

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a8f17c52d2c01289999eba7e5fa893a45b0204e2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L386-L402)

Comment: Haha, for some reason I always write up some nifty code for functionality that Laravel seems to provide out of the box. Good call!

Comment: Thank you so much, I was in holiday i forgot to mark as answer :)

Comment: @Radu No problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough Laravel to know if this can actually work (as in, it will actually switch databases), but plain old OOP tells me it can be programmed like this:

**Model**

```
const SQL_JATO = 'sqljato';
const SQL_JATO_TWO = 'sqljato2'

public function setDbConnection(string $connection)
{
    $this->connection = $connection;
}
```

**Controller**

```
$jato = new version_jato([$attributes]); // Put something in here
$jato->setDbConnection(version_jato::SQL_JATO_TWO);
$jato->save();
```

Comment: Thank you dear sir!