# How to store Auth session

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new in Laravel and firebase and I did the login and password validation by myself, but I would like to use the  `Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']])`, function to protect unauthorized access to the system, but I don't know how to tell Laravel that the user is already authenticated without using `Auth::attempt($credentials)`.

So how can I set the user is authenticated already, redirect the user to main page passing the login(name of the user) to Auth.

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) { //I need to replace this line setting the user is logged already
  return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

I tried: `Auth()->login($nickname);`

But I received:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, string given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Auth()->login($user);
```

is the right method, you should pass $user object instead of a string which includes user nickname, for example:

```
$use = new User();
$user->id = 1;
$user->email = 'eshtiaghi.amin@gmail.com';
$user->name = $nickname;
$user->save();
\Auth::login($user);
```

Comment: Partially this solves the problem but I can't use $user->save cause I'm using firebase so I deleted it and login, but in home page when I use: {{Auth::user()->nickname}}, it tryes to make a select on a database that do not exist, I thought that it was stored in session, is there a way to deactive this? I still don't get to use: Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function()

Comment: because user model database by default set to use mysql database, but you can change it in your model, please have a look at this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264675/laravel-5-how-to-change-a-model-database-connection-within-controller

Comment: @LucianoCoelho, my pleasure